# django - Is it possible to access multiple databases without declaring in settings.py file?

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlalchemy

Every time a Company is created I want to create an individual database to store corresponding values.

models.py(company App)

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py (company App)

```
class AddCompany(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    mode = Company
    form_class = AddCompanyForm
    template_name = "add_company.html"
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

models.py(Inventory App)

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey('company.Company')
```

views.py(Inventory App)

```
class AddToInventory(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model =Inventory
    form_class = AddToInventoryForm
    template_name = "add_inventory.html"
```

Is it possible to access a database without declaring the database in `settings.py` file and without using any routes. I want the items belonging to each company to be stored in a separate database if the database of company does not exist then a new database has to be created and I have to be able to read and write data from the databases without using any routes.

Is it possible to do something like with django by using some SQLAlchemy?

Is this even possible with django?

Comment: I'd say ditch Django and use SQLAlchemy. The search term you're looking for is "multi tenant" or so.